# Contracted verb: Negative, positive, which one is it and why?

Tags: grammar, verbs, contractions

[image: contraction]

I've encountered the negative contraction several times since I started to study japanese, and I understand the logic behind the transformation from 開かない/開かぬ　to 開かん in the first picture.

A similar transformation seems to occur in the following two sentences, とならん　and ならん. However, when I check the translation the form of the verbs are positive.

There is something I'm missing and I can't find the key to know the difference between this similar sounding contractions.

Comment: Where do you "check the translation"? Could you maybe give those translations here?

Comment: The pics are from the videogame Final Fantasy Type Zero HD. 

I do the checking by viewing youtube Let's Play videos from the English version.

The official translation of my pictures says as this:
-
-

Comment: The official translation of my pictures says as this:
-"The gate won't open? What the hell is going on?"
-"We, the Militesi Empire, will become Agito, the hand that guides Orience!"
-"May the path you follow be bright"
Respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「ならん」has two distinct meanings.  The current common meaning is an abbreviation of ならない・ならぬ with an emphatic nuance.  The other is an abbreviation of　「[ならむ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/165308/meaning/m0u/)」which is an obsolete equivalent to だろう・であろう - now mostly found in 時代劇。(Your example is the latter - ならむ)

「あらん」is used in [religious](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1052862080) and other [profound circumstances](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%A8%E5%85%B1%E3%81%AB%E3%81%82%E3%82%89%E3%82%93%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%82%92) to pray/wish for something good.  Also more likely to find あらん in 時代劇